# Ending code-execution with a keypress at anytime

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import keyboard
import mouse

def doStuff(offset, duration):
    x = offset
    y = 0
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
        mouse.move(x=x, y=y, absolute=False, duration=duration)
        temp = y
        x *= -1
        y = x
        x = temp

def main():
     doStuff(50, 0.2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My goal is to end the doStuff()-method at any given moment and not only after the Mouse has been moved into one direction. I would also like not using the Ctrl-C KeyboardInterrupt, since I want to bind a custom key to the action.

Answer (score 0):

function mouse.move waits for moving mouse.

we need to make mouse.move function, what accepts exit

i do this.

```
import keyboard
import time
import win32api
print(win32api.GetCursorPos())


def map(x, in_max): # fit number to 0-1
    return x / in_max


def lerp(v0: float, v1: float, t: float): # control x and y by number 0-1
    return (1 - t) * v0 + t * v1


def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((int(x),int(y))) # move cursor


def move(x, y, d):
    tmr = time.time()
    x1, y1 = win32api.GetCursorPos() #get last cursor pos
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'): #interrupt
            exit(KeyboardInterrupt)
        click(x1 + lerp(0, x, map(time.time() - tmr, d)), (y1 + lerp(0, y, map(time.time() - tmr, d)))) #set local position of mouse
        if time.time() - tmr > d: # if duration ends
            break


def doStuff(offset, duration):
    x = offset
    y = 0
    while True:
        move(x, y, duration)
        temp = y
        x *= -1
        y = x
        x = temp

def main():
     doStuff(50, 0.2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

if you need to use global position:

```
def move(x, y, d):
    tmr = time.time()
    x1, y1 = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
            exit(KeyboardInterrupt)
        click(lerp(0, x, map(time.time() - tmr, d)), (lerp(0, y, map(time.time() - tmr, d))))
        if time.time() - tmr > d:
            break
```

Comment: If I want to add pauses between each rectangle or each movement of the cursor and still be able to cancel the programm, how would you do that ?

Comment: then your code is work as you need. if I understood correctly. You can add pauses using time.sleep(), but my code won't be work